# Calculate the double integral using polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polar-coordinates

$$I=\iint\limits_{D}\operatorname{ctg}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy = \iint\limits_D \operatorname{ctg}\left(\sqrt{r^2\cos^2 \theta +r^2\sin^2 \theta}\right) \, r \, dr \, d\theta =$$
$$=\iint\limits_D r \operatorname{ctg} r \, dr \, d\theta =\int\limits_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int\limits_0^1 r \operatorname{ctg} r \, dr = 2\pi \int\limits_0^1 r\operatorname{ctg} r \, dr$$
$$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq1\}$$
I tried to calculate it but it doesn't work

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%280+to+1%29+xctg%28x%29dx

Comment: Are you sure the integral is cotangent instead of inverse tangent? The two are not the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is exactly a cotangent (cot(x))

Comment: The set of points $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$ is the circumfrence of the circle. As posed, the integral should be zero.

Comment: Can you show me why it's 0?

Comment: what is $ctg$?  Are those constant?

Comment: that's another notation for cotangent.

Comment: The remaining integral is only expressible using dilogarithms (or [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function)).